# StreamSocketListener only works once; the second call fails

Tags: c#, uwp, asyncsocket, windows-iot-core-10

Any help on the issue below would be highly appreciated. I'm using the StreamSocketListener Class to accept TCP/IP connection on my Raspberry Pi 3 running windows IoT 10 Core.

This is my server code so far:

```
static string _maintenancePort = "8888";

public async static void StartListening()
{
    try
    {
        StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();
        var currentSetting = listener.Control.QualityOfService;
        listener.Control.QualityOfService = SocketQualityOfService.LowLatency;
        listener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;
        listener.Control.KeepAlive = true;
        await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(_maintenancePort);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.WriteErrorLog(e);
    }
}

private static async void SocketListener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        Log.WriteDebugLog("Incoming data...");

        Stream inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inStream);
        string request = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

        if (request != null)
        {
            Log.WriteDebugLog("Received : " + request);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.WriteErrorLog(e);
    }
}
```

I wrote the following client code to connect to the socket. This code runs on another machine.

```
    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private static String response = String.Empty;
    public static Socket client;

    public static string SendMessageToClient(string ip, int port, string message, bool expectResponse)
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.  
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  

            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            message += "^" + expectResponse.ToString();

            // Send test data to the remote device.  
            Send(client, message);
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            if (expectResponse)
            {
                Receive(client);
                receiveDone.WaitOne();
            }

            // Release the socket.  
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Write(e, false);
            return "";
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Log.WriteSingleMessage(String.Format("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent), false);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.  
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Write(e, false);
        }
    }
}
```

The client code is triggered by a button click event. The problem that I'm facing is that the server code above only works once. If I send a message to the server with the client code, the server processes the string perfect. However, if I hit the button a second time, the SocketListener_ConnectionReceived event is triggered but no data is coming in. I've tried several classes for ConnectionReceived but they all behave the same.

I checked with netstat on the Raspberry Pi if the server is listening and it is.

> TCP    0.0.0.0:8888           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Even child processes are created for handling the connection as you would expect from an Async calls. The client code closes the socket after it received a message that the data has been send (waitOne()) and the socket on the client machines changes to CLOSE_WAIT.

> TCP    10.0.102.10:8888       10.0.100.11:31298      CLOSE_WAIT
>   TCP    10.0.102.10:8888       10.0.100.11:31299      ESTABLISHED

Can anyone help me out and point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong. any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Really strange. Just for the sake of not being rude, I added 'dear all' to the top of my question but it was removed twice. My sincere apoligies :)

Comment: This case is  [tag:windows-iot-core-10] related, please add the tag for this case.

Comment: Nothing seems to reset your events in the client. Without those being reset, I'd expect the second and subsequent attempts to run that code to have "issues".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use synchronous methods instead asynchronous methods for socket client. It will work. Please refer to following code:

```
    public void SendMessageToClientSync(string ip, int port, string message, bool expectResponse)
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.  
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        // Connect to a remote device.  
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
            // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.  
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.  
            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.  
            try
            {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                    sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.  
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Send the data through the socket.  
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                if(expectResponse)
                {
                    // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                    int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                    Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
                }

                // Release the socket.  
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```